# Handle the case when a user deletes an image in Zefyr

Tags: flutter, wysiwyg

I've hooked up my image delegate according [the docs here](https://zefyr-editor.gitbook.io/docs/images). The only notable change is that my `pickImage` function uses filePicker instead and also immediately stores the user's image, returning the address to the image in firebase.

```dart
@override
Future<String> pickImage(bool isGallery) async {
  if (!isGallery) return null;

  final filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.IMAGE);

  if (filePath == null) return null;

  final fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  final iconRef = storageReference.child('page_images').child(fileName);
  final uploadTask = iconRef.putFile(File(filePath));

  final snapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  final downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  return downloadUrl;
}
```

What is a good way to figure out when a user has deleted this image so that I can remove it from storage as well? Listening to the `changes` I can get all the `Operation`s and iterate through them to tell me which were deletes but I don't think there's data attached to see *what* was deleted:

```dart
textController.document.changes.listen((NotusChange change) {
  for (var i = 0; i < change.change.length; i++) {
    final operation = change.change.elementAt(i);

    if (operation.isDelete) {
      print('Value: ${operation.value}'); // Prints number of deleted characters

      // This is just for inserts, else it's null
      print('Value: ${operation.data}');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. There's an `invert` method on a `Delta` that you can use to essentially get the opposite of the transformation just made. Zefyr uses this to do undo's I think. As opposed to a `delete` an `insert` carries with it the changes meant to be applied including the attributes (i.e. images) to add to the text:

```dart
textController.document.changes.listen((NotusChange change) {
  final undoDelta = change.change.invert(change.before);

  for (final operation in undoDelta.toList()) {
    // Since `invert is essentially an undo, an isInsert would
    // correspond to an isDelete.
    if (operation.isInsert && operation.hasAttribute('embed')) {
      final embedPath = operation.attributes['embed']['source'] as String;
      print(embedPath);
    }
  }
});
```